# Encrypt multiple strings that have 2 or few values

Tags: encryption, aes

I want to AES encrypt information in a database, that can have just a few values. E.g. I want to encrypt the gender and the value can only be "male" and "female".
The encryption key for multiple rows is the same (cannot guarantee a unique key for each row).
My question: Is it safe to just encrypt the raw value or is it better to pad the original value with random noise and an stop character before encryption:

`male` -> `214214.male.73297` -> `[encryptedtext]`(after decryption, the noise can be removed.)

Or is there other best practices for this issue?

Comment: Use a random IV, this way you get different cipher text each time.

Comment: What is the point of encryption? The best practice would be to actually harden your server so that attackers cannot exploit easy vulnerabilities and get in instead of trying to encrypt data where the key is stored in the same place.

Comment: @EbbeM.Pedersen I already use random IV. The question is if its enough for this case.

Comment: The random IV removes the need for adding random data in the message prior to encryption. Using the IV is best practice.